# Devart LinqConnect for mysql A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: mysql, linq, devart

I couldn't solve this problem after linqConnect For Mysql generated entity of models for me. I thought devart is good software, without testing trial period, I purchased their license, but now I am facing this issue, I couldn't even get it working. please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp2MA.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The the piece of code highlighted is "System.String.Empty", nothing is wrong here. A similar problem is discussed, for example, at [Visual Studio 2015: Intellisense errors but solution compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943634/visual-studio-2015-intellisense-errors-but-solution-compiles). Have you tried to build a project ignoring these fantom errors? Most likely, the build will succeed in this case. To avoid displaying such misleading "errors", choose "Build Only" droplist value (instead of "Build + IntelliSense") in the Error List window from your screenshot.