# C++ Visual studio 2017 Intellisense marks error but build successfully

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

In C++ develop (mostly Cocos2d-x)

Visual studio 2017 marks red-line some namespace and class members. (like "..." is ambiguous, incomplete type not allowed)

also autocomplete is not working.
build and run works fine. (weird)

sometimes Intellisense works fine. doesn't marks red-line and autocomplete also.

it makes me sick

I've tried uninstall and clean visual studio 2017 and re-install and updated most recent version

but still

any solutions?

Comment: Sounds like intellisense is doing what it was suppose to do which is to help you identify some potential problems with your code early on.  So your choice really is to turn off intellisense, or figure out what is tripping it up.  This is a common issue with big projects.

Comment: You could also try the solutions in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943634/visual-studio-2015-intellisense-errors-but-solution-compiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IntelliSense Limitations**

IntelliSense does not work in C++ projects under the following circumstances:

- The cursor is in a code comment.
- You are writing a string literal.
- A syntax error appears over the cursor.
- The solution consists of either the syntax for managed C++, or the earlier Managed Extensions for C++ syntax.
- IntelliSense is not fully supported when you reference a header file multiple times by using the `#include` directive, and the meaning of that header file changes because of various macro states that are defined through the `#define` directive. In other words, when you include a header file several times and the header usage changes under different macro states, IntelliSense does not always work.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235519.aspx