# No operator >> matches these operands ifstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am coding in Visual Studio Code, using C++. I am getting the following error, "no operator >> matches these operands". Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? (The error is occurring on the line, `fin >> N.`)

```
#include <fstream>

int solve() {
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("race3.in");
    int N;
    fin>>N;

    std::ofstream fout;
    fout.open("race3.out");

    fout.close();
    fin.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full error message? (There should be more information below this line in the output.) I cannot reproduce your error. The only problem I see is that your function does not return a value although it is declared to do so.

Comment: Hello, here is the full error message: 'no operator ">>" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::ifstream >> int' at: '31,8' source: '' code: 'undefined'. My compiler is MinGW

Comment: In particular, we need to know what compiler you use.

Comment: @MihirShah Is that output from the actual compilation or is it just a hint from your IDE? MinGW's error messages look different.

Comment: I went to the command line and ran g++ filename.cpp, and I got no error. However Visual Studio Code is still showing the error.

Comment: @MihirShah Then this is not a problem with your code, but a problem with the VS Code settings. Since I don't know about them, someone else will have to answer that.

Comment: Are you completely sure that VS code uses MinGW? Can you also attach a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Sorry I fixed the problem, the intellisense mode was set to msvc-x64. I set it to clang-x64 and the error disappeared. Thank you!

Comment: It's still strange. I tested it with msvc-x64: https://godbolt.org/z/Br888q . You may want to report a bug.

Comment: Note that [intellisense errors don't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31943634/10957435) really because they can be finicky. What ultimately matters is does it compile when you hit "compile" and does the compiler throw an error (or warning)? If it does, then you actually have a problem.

Comment: @dyukha As OP commented, this is not actually a compilation error. They simply had setup their IDE wrong and presumably it was looking in the wrong directory for include files or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from the comments, it seems to be a Intellisense problem.

I should note that in the future, that [Intellisense can be finicky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31943634/10957435) and prone to errors occasionally.

The best way to know that you really have an error is to hit "compile" and see what comes back. If it gives you an error message, then there is really something wrong. If it doesn't, then Intellisense could just be acting up.

As for this specific case, there looks like there is nothing wrong with your code, so it is likely just an Intellisense error. Here are some [possible causes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46665962/10957435), but there is no way to know for sure this side of the computer.