# Visual Studio 2015 IntelliSense error but solution compiles

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I know that there's already been [a thread like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943634/visual-studio-2015-intellisense-errors-but-solution-compiles) but I've tried everything that was suggested and the error is still showing in the editor but the solution compiles okay. My problem might be a bit different though.

I have a function called `getCurrentTime` with the same name, defined in two separate files and inherited to different classes. This is how it looks:
[image]

[image]

`NetworkClientState` uses `getCurrentTime` from the `NetworkClient` base class.
`GameClient` as well as `LinearPrediction` and `QuadraticPrediction` all use `getCurrentTime` define in the `Prediction` base class.

Intellisense persist on underscoring `Prediction::getCurrentTime` but the program compiles and runs. Although it will say that `getCurrentTime` is ambiguous if I get rid of `using NetworkClient::getCurrentTime`. 
What could I do to get rid of this Intellisense error?

Comment: This is obviously a bug in IntelliSense. The only solution is to either ignore it or upgrade your IDE (Visual Studio 2017 has been available for a long while already). That said, you should create a [MCVE] if issue persists in the newest IDE version and then report it through the appropriate channels.

Comment: Remember IntelliSense is a separate compiler that is optimized for speed not necessarily accuracy. It will have false positives.

Comment: Why do you use Prediction? You don’t derive from it.

Comment: Why is getCurrentTime a member of any class? The name suggests that it should be a free function.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments! I'll try VS2017 and see what happens. Cheers!

Comment: @carrotcake, it is works fine in VS 2017?

Comment: @sara-liu-msft I deleted last comments because after compiling the project the error still persists in VS2017.

Comment: @tambre the error still persists in VS2017.

Comment: @carrotcake Make sure to delete the hidden `.vs` directory for the solution to force a re-index. If the problem persists, then create a [MCVE].

Comment: @tambre problem solved! Also, I've changed my application so `getCurrentTime` is in one file now and I'm no longer overloading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it by popping `Prediction::getCurrentTime` into the `.cpp` file and then just removing the declaration from the header file. The error was probably popping up because of the multiple inheritance.